# EF6: Your project references the latest version of EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm using visual studio 2012 EF6 + SQLite while I'm about to create the model

[Your project references the latest version of EF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmIFC.jpg)

Packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages xmlns="urn:packages">
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.Core" version="1.0.109.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" version="1.0.109.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </configSections>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
            <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="v11.0" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
    </entityFramework>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Installed Packages

```
Id                             Version              Description/Release Notes                                                                                                           
--                             -------              -------------------------                                                                                                           
EntityFramework                6.2.0                Entity Framework is Microsoft's recommended data access technology for new applications.                                            
System.Data.SQLite             1.0.109.1            The official SQLite database engine for both x86 and x64 along with the ADO.NET provider.  This package includes support for LINQ...
System.Data.SQLite.Core        1.0.109.1            The official SQLite database engine for both x86 and x64 along with the ADO.NET provider.                                           
System.Data.SQLite.EF6         1.0.109.0            Support for Entity Framework 6 using System.Data.SQLite.                                                                            
System.Data.SQLite.Linq        1.0.109.0            Support for LINQ using System.Data.SQLite.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Get a lower version nuget package of the framework?

Comment: The message teels the framework is not compatible for sql-lite

Comment: Is there an actual question here?